# C# Dynamically Add Columns to table in Database

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am still learning quite a bit about programming so this may be an obvious question but I am in the process of writing a program where a user can import an excel file with no column constraints (meaning each excel file could have a different number of columns and so on).  What I want to do is be able to convert the imported excel file into a database table using SQLite. As far as I have read the syntax for SQLite is the same as ADO syntax but I am unsure of how to dynamically create the tables in the database.  I am looking for any form of suggestions, if someone felt like showing an example in code that would be cool.

Thanks!
Nathan

Comment: Is it possible to look into another solution. Creating a table for every file loaded is a bad idea, think of having 10000's of tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a piece of code for creating a table in sqlite:

```
SQLiteConnection mDBcon = new SQLiteConnection();
mDBcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + DataSourcePath;
mDBcon.Open();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(mDBcon);
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tags (ISBN VARCHAR(15), Tag VARCHAR(15));";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

note that in SQLite you can only add coloumn to existing tables, and only to the end of the table:

```
cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE books ADD COLUMN PublishDate DateTime;";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Addition**

Assuming you imported you data from the excel to a DataSet,
you can now iterate through the DataSet's DataTables, create the corresponding tables and fill them:
(disclaimer, haven't tested it)

```
foreach(DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
{
    SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(mDBcon);
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table.Name + "(";
    bool first = true;
    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {           
        cmd.CommandText += "@"+column.Name;
        if (!first) cmd.CommandText += ",";
        else first = false;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@"+column.Name, column.Name));
    }
    cmd.CommandText += ");";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Fill the new table:
    SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from " + table.Name, mDBcon);
    da.Fill(table);
}
```

Comment: Ah I didn't know you had to already had to have a table made but that's no biggy.  I guess my main problem is I can't figure out how to progromattically get the column names from the excel file, get their associated types and then some how turn that into the Create Table statement.  If I turn the import into a dataset could I use the dataset schema as my database table schema?

Comment: @Nathan: haven't used dataset to import data into sqlite, but since it has full ADO support, i assume you can.

Comment: Can you think of an example of how I would take column from the dataset and use ADO to add it the Create Table statement?

Comment: wow, thanks I will take this and work it into my code.  I will let you know how it works out tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) to create your table, using the standard [SQLite Query Language for CREATE TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).